# How to iterate nested array and objects using handlebars (hbs)?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, each

I am iterating nested array from JSON. There are objects nested in a few levels. I need to fetch the first image from the second array in `image_groups` property. So far I've managed to reach the `link` property, but I can not choose the only one particular link that I need instead of all links of images in the array.

Code:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
   {{#each image_groups~}}
   {{#each images~}}
   <h6>{{title}}</h6>
   <img src="../images/{{link}}" alt="{{alt}}">
   {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

Screenshot of JSON:
[image]

How it's showing in the browser:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what "the only one particular link that I need" means. Each image looks to have just a single `link`, so perhaps it is a single image from the `images` array that you want to target?

Comment: @76484, you are right! I want to target only one link. I want to show on the page only one image.

Comment: You will need to express some logic which determines _which_ image from each `images` array is to be your target. Is it the first? The last? Which image do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to find the solution. I should go out of the **each** loop and tye the next string:

```
<img
 src="../images/{{image_groups.0.images.0.link}}"
 alt="{{image_groups.0.images.0.alt}}"
>
```

Comment: This isn't a very clear answer. Are you still using the `{{#each image_groups~}}` loop?

Comment: No, I shouldn't not go into {{#each image_groups~}} loop. Sorry, for an unclear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on resolving your issue!

I would like to propose an alternative solution which I think makes for a cleaner template.

As we have established that we no longer need either of `#each` loops because we are after only the first image of the first image_group, we can see that we are left with just the `<h6>` and `<img>` tags. The values to be populated for both of these tags all come from our target image object.

I would propose using Handlebars' [#with built-in helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#with). This helper allows us to set the data context for a piece of our template. Setting the context to our target image object will save us from re-writing its long path, allowing us to access its properties simply and cleanly as, for example, `{{title}}`.

The final template with `#with` would be:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  {{#with image_groups.[0].images.[0]}}
    <h6>{{title}}</h6>
    <img
      alt="{{alt}}"
      src="{{link}}"
    >
  {{/with}}
</div>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/nfkvyLc5/) for your reference.